# Add xml values to list in foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, loops, iteration

I'm having a problem figuring out how to add values to a list in a foreach loop. I want to take values from an XML doc (using xpath at the moment) and add the values to the list. I've run into an error where c# doesn't allow you to assign directly to foreach iteration variables, so I'm not sure exactly how I would get the values into the list without assigning directly to the variable.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <options>
        <option>true</option>
        <option>false</option>
    </options>
</config>
```

Here's my code:

```
        List<string> options = null;

        foreach(string option in options)
        {
            option = config.XPathSelectElement("//config/options/option").Value;
            options.Add(option);
        }
```

I'm getting the error right now that I can't assign to an iteration variable. Would I be better off performing a query using Linq?

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate through a null collection? What's `config`?

Comment: You need to iterate over XML - not List.

Comment: There are many mistakes, e.g. your XPath query (config/options) does not match with your XML structure (config/optionList); your are iterating over `options` which is null, and if it were not null, it still is *not* the object to iterate over (instead you should use a selection of the elements of `config` as the source); and doing repeated calls to `config.XPathSelectElement("//config/options/option")` will always retrieve the same value.

Comment: iterating over a list with `foreach` provides you with each of the *existing* values in an *existing* list. You don't even have a list, much less one with values in it. Please make some effort to find some example code or read some documentation before you start writing code. You can't just dream up some weird theory off the top of your head, based on nothing, and then start pretending it's true. That approach is guaranteed to fail in hopeless, incomprehensible ways.

Comment: Also, your XML won't parse.

Comment: Ed, Please understand that I did search for hours looking for code that would accomplish what I wanted to do. I'm coming from Ruby and C# is a little different in how it handles this. It's a little off-putting that you assumed I didn't work at all towards finding an answer on my own before posting here and even more frustrating that your tone towards my question was so negative. if you're here to help, I appreciate it, but if you're here to degrade the question I'd prefer that you just move along. I do see that you posted an answer below that accomplishes precisely what I was looking for

Comment: , so it would seem that you have at least an idea of what I was looking to do. I appreciate your answer, but your attitude sucks. I'm here to learn, not to be lectured.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the XML so it parses, this will get you a `List<String>` containing the inner text of the `option` elements.

```
var config = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<config>
    <optionList>
        <option>true</option>
        <option>false</option>
    </optionList>
</config>");

List<String> options = new List<string>();

//  We're now calling XPathSelectElements() -- elementS, plural. We want all
//  of them, not just the first one. 
foreach (var elem in config.XPathSelectElements("/config/optionList/option"))
{
    options.Add(elem.Value);
}
```

First, we create the list we want to add items to. Then we use the `foreach` loop to iterate through the collection that already has stuff in it.

You could do this with LINQ, but it's far more important right now for you to understand how `foreach` loops are used.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have an error in your XML file as you have a closing `</directories>` tag which isn't opened.

New XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <optionList>
        <option>true</option>
        <option>false</option>
    </optionList>
</config>
```

Load the XML...

```
XmlDocument memberLists = new XmlDocument();
            memberLists.Load(pathname);

            XmlNodeList memberlist = memberLists.SelectNodes("//config/optionlist");
```

Retrieve the information you need...

```
                List<string> options = null;

                string option = "";
                foreach (XmlNode node in memberlist)
                {
                    option = node.SelectSingleNode("option").InnerText;
                    options.add(option); //Put the value into the list.
                }
```

Hope this is what you needed.